# Find float in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Is there any function in Objective-C that is similar to `array_search` in PHP? I'm trying to make one that should work, but the logic is not right.

```
-(BOOL)searchInArray :(NSMutableArray *)allData :(float)dataToFind {
    BOOL *temp = false;

    for(int i=0;i<=[allData count];i++){
        if([[allData objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] == dataToFind){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is almost right. The problem is that if the first element in the array doesn't match the `float` you're searching for then the method will return `false` without looking at the rest of the array.

What you want to do is return `true` if any of the array elements match, and only return `false` when the whole array has been looked at and none of them match.

```
- (BOOL)searchInArray:(NSMutableArray *)allData forFloat:(float)dataToFind {
    for (int i = 0; i < [allData count]; i++) {
        if ([[allData objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] == dataToFind) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

A more modern/readable version might look like this:

```
- (BOOL)array:(NSMutableArray *)array containsFloat:(float)theFloat {
    for (NSObject *object in array) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            NSNumber *number = (NSNumber *)object;
            if (number.floatValue == theFloat) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This version has a few changes from the original:

- It uses `YES` and `NO` instead of `true` and `false`; this is recommended for Objective C code.
- It uses a for-each loop instead of accessing the array by index; this is more readable.
- It checks each element of the array to make sure it's a number before trying to get the `floatValue`; this will prevent errors occurring if your array contains things that aren't numbers.

Comment: That and it should be `i < [allData count]` instead of `i <= [allData count]`. Otherwise you'll get an out of bounds exception. Also fast enumeration would be a better way of looping through.

Comment: And `i` should be `NSInteger`, not `int`. And `true` and `false` should be `YES` and `NO`.

Comment: Whoops, I missed the comparison, thanks @originaluser2. I left the indexing and `true`/`false` for minimal change but I've added a more modern version now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
- (BOOL)searchInArray:(NSArray<NSNumber *> *)array forFloat:(float)floatToFind
{
    for (NSNumber *number in array) {
        if (number.floatValue == floatToFind) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This would be the better answer if you added an explanation of what the issue was and how this fixes the problem.

Comment: This adds the <NSNumber *> generic to the NSArray *array parameter specification so the compiler will spit out an error if you try to pass an NSArray of anything else.